# Two-way binding between child template and object property in parent template view model?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

We are building a form-based app to allow users to edit properties of a multi-level nested object. When passing an object property as a named view-model attribute on a child element, the binding does not seem to work:

https://gist.run/?id=b04915bc1f3b8675ea159b9a481d68e8

What should I change, so the child template has a two-way binding with a property of an object in the parent template view model?

Comment: I can consider passing the root object in to the child templates, rather than trying to two-way bind a property. However, due to the nested nature of the object we are modeling, I am hoping we can pass attributes of the top level object and sub objects into child templates.

Comment: I have a binding behavior that will likely help you do what you are wanting to do. Check it out here: https://gist.run/?id=8fb1a6c144253b7f361145b1b5f7b05c please get in touch with me so I can set up a session to go through this code with you and your team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a bindable `info` to `open-api-info.js`:

```
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class OpenApiInfo {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay }) info = {};
  constructor() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}
```

Updated gist: https://gist.run/?id=ce6e048f043fdc752815cec324c4ea1c

Comment: This only gives 1 way data binding. You have to configure it for two way databinding.

Comment: It's included in the view template of the gist but you're right. I'll edit the answer.